# Photo Keywords and Databases- Which implementation?

Tags: mysql, database-design

As a personal exercise, I'm building a photo site and implementing keyword search.  Currently, I'm in the early stages of the design process and am at a fork.

Which is better

- having a `keyword` field in the photo table and executing `FULLTEXT` searches
- Separate keyword table with each word referencing `n` images

This may be a case of premature optimization, but I would like some guidance.

Comment: having tags or keywords is more suggested as your photo site performance would be very high if you do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a single way in which your database design would be improved by using the `FULLTEXT` approach.  The separate keyword table speeds searching, allows declarative relational integrity to be applied to the keyword list, makes gathering statistics much easier, and will be more portable across engines.